# Move Folder Using App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

So i'm brand new to JS and trying to build a program for internal operation at the company I work for. Below is the first bit of my code. I have a created a google form, and set a trigger so that when the submit button is clicked the below code will start. The trigger works and the first two functions work, but I cannot seem to get the Karrie folder to move from the root to the sub folder id (I do have the correct ID but omitted it from this post). Maybe I'm doing this all backwards so any help would be appreciated.

```
// Create Karrie Folder In Root
function start() {

var sourceFolder = "Property Template";
var targetFolder = "Karrie"; 
var source = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sourceFolder);
var target = DriveApp.createFolder(targetFolder);
if (source.hasNext()) {
  copyFolder(source.next(), target);}}

// Adds Property data to Karrie Folder
function copyFolder(source, target) {
var folders = source.getFolders();
var files   = source.getFiles();
while(files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  file.makeCopy(file.getName(), target);}

// Adds Photo Folders to Karrie Folder
while(folders.hasNext()) {
var subFolder = folders.next();
var folderName = subFolder.getName();
var targetFolder = target.createFolder(folderName);
  copyFolder(subFolder, targetFolder);}} 


// Moves Karrie folder to propertie folder
function MoveFiles(){
var files = DriveApp.getFolderByName("Karrie");
   var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID NA");
   destination.addFolder(files);}
```

[Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Im9Df.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

I understood that `MoveFiles()` in your script doesn't work. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- In order to move a folder, it required to move the parent of the folder.
- But when `addFolder()` is used to the folder, the folder has 2 parents.

  - So original parent has to be removed.
- There is no `getFolderByName()`. Please use `getFoldersByName()`.

#### Modified script :

```
function MoveFiles(){
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Karrie").next();
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID NA");
  destination.addFolder(folder);
  folder.getParents().next().removeFolder(folder);
}
```

#### Note :

- In this script, The folder and parent of `"Karrie"` supposes only one in the Google Drive, respectively.

#### References :

- [getFoldersByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfoldersbynamename)
- [addFolder()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#addFolder(Folder))
- [removeFolder()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#removefolderchild)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

### Edit 1 :

When you run this function, does the ID of `Logger.log(r)` show the folderId of "Karrie"?

```
function sample() {
  var r = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Karrie").next().getId();
  Logger.log(r)
}
```

### Edit 2 :

Please confirm and consider the following points.

1. Confirm the folder name and the existence of the folder again.
2. Run `sample()` and confirm folder ID of "Karrie".
3. Confirm whether there are no functions with the same name.
4. Can I ask you the folder ID of "Karrie"? If you cannot retrieve the folder ID using `DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Karrie").next().getId()`, I propose to use directly the folder ID of "Karrie".

### Updated on March 30, 2022:

In the current stage, the files and folders can be moved using `moveTo`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2020#july_27_2020) This method has added on July 27, 2020. When `moveTo` is used, the above script can be modified as follows.

```js
function MoveFiles(){
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Karrie").next();
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID NA");
  folder.moveTo(destination);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [moveTo(destination) of Class Folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#moveTo(Folder))

Comment: Yes you have an understanding of my problem, so made the changes to my script that you suggested, but the folder still didn't move from the root to the sub folder.

Comment: @Robert Johnson Thank you for your reply. In my environment, the modified script works. So can I ask you about the situation? Did some error occur? Did you run the script on your Google Drive?

Comment: no errors at all, that is what confuses me. The karrie folder does appear in the root, but doesn't show up in the sub folder where it should be moved to.

Comment: @Robert Johnson I added a sample script. When you run the function, does the ID of ``Logger.log(r)`` show the folderId of "Karrie"?

Comment: no, i ran the script using the debugger and nothing was returned

Comment: @Robert Johnson What is the debugger? Can you run it normally?

Comment: the little bug next to the play button.

Comment: @Robert Johnson If ``DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Karrie").next().getId()`` doesn't show the folderId, please confirm the folder name and the existence of the folder again.

Comment: @Robert Johnson Can I ask you about the little bug?

Comment: and yes i ran it using the button as well. I think your starting figure out why I'm confused, but i'm still clueless and your probably getting somewhere.

Comment: @Robert Johnson Please try "Run" -> "Run function" -> ``sample()`` or ``MoveFiles()``. And also please confirm whether there are no functions with the same name.

Comment: I added a screen shot of the debugger button and the run button to my post so you know what I was talking about. And all the code that is in my post is all that there is, I just started this project today, and like I said, i'm just now learning (i come from a VBA background and was just novice at that)

Comment: @Robert Johnson I added the points for confirming and considering. Please check it. And can I ask you about the answers.

Comment: @Robert Johnson I saw the image. As an another way for running function, on the script editor, please try "Run" -> "Run function" -> sample() or MoveFiles().

Comment: is the folder Id supposed to be the Id of the Karrie folder or the sub folder, because I have been using the sub folder Id?

Comment: @Robert Johnson In my proposal, both folder IDs are used. Can you show them? When you show them, I would like to modify the script of my answer. If you cannot do it, please add them to the script.

Comment: so then I guess i'm confused as to how i'm supposed to get the Id if the folder doesn't exist until after the script runs

Comment: @Robert Johnson I cannot understand your situation. In your question, you want to move a folder. Also you said "Yes you have an understanding of my problem". But in your latest comment, it seems that my understanding is wrong. Can I ask you about the detail information what you want to do? I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: I have a "Property Template" folder that is being copied, then the script is creating the folder "Karrie" in the root, after that, the script adds the sub folders that were copied and pastes them into the Karrie folder. Because the Karrie folder is in the root, I need to move it to a sub folder called "Properties". I hope this clears things up for you, and thank you for your help

Comment: @Robert Johnson As a test for modified ``MoveFiles()``, please run ``MoveFiles()`` under the situation that the folder of "Karrie" is existing in root of the Google Drive. And also confirm the folder ID of the destination subfolder that you want to move.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you are asking, i'm sure it would be clear if I were not so new to this, but I am. Can you dumb it down for me?

Comment: @Robert Johnson I'm sorry for my poor English skill. Can you try to do the following flow? 1. Create manually a folder of "Karrie" in the root on your Google Drive. 2. Run the function ``MoveFiles()`` by click "Run" -> "Run function" -> "MoveFiles()". 3. Confirm the result. If this didn't work, please confirm my Edit 2 again and tell me the results.

Comment: @Robert Johnson And can you give me a time to do my work? I require to have a time to do. So my response may become a bit slow. I'm sorry for this situation.

Comment: it returned "MoveFiles" is not defined

Comment: @Robert Johnson I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. From your latest comment, I would like to recommend to check this page. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview

Answer (score 0):

As of 2020, the easier way I found to move a file is to use this function:

```
function moveToFolder(file, sourceFolder, destFolder) {
   var file = DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId());
   destFolder.addFile(file);
   sourceFolder.removeFile(file);
}
```

Because of the first line, you can convert your `Spreadsheet`, Google `Form`, `Document` or others Google objects into a `File`.

Then we just use methods of the `Folder` class : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder

Notes:

- If you created your file by using `.create()` your sourceFolder will be `DriveApp.getRootFolder()`.
- If you have multiple files to move, just iterate over them.